# Drop down alignment issue with chrome

Tags: drop-down-menu

My first question with Stackoverflow.
Please help to my issue.
I have vertical dropdown menu (in top) feature for my project. It worked well initially. But when I included a third party Modal script, in the same page, the dropdown menu (in top) misaligned in Chrome and Firefox, but works well in IE. My chrome version 21.0.xxxx

Here is my URL http://www.tcarts.in/dep_tamil.php (Under Faculty, in middle of the page, I included Modal script)

Answer (score 0):

Place the *submenu* `div` after their *parent menu* in the `td` and work on the *css* . . You will get the *submenu* drop under the *parent menu*.